# How to simplify a slide change in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What is the best way to simplify a slide change?

I use "Gradient Overlay" and moving the circle, but it takes a lot of time.

I need to take a lot of different pictures with other values.

[image]

PSD file: https://we.tl/t-dyLOKgncE8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about moving the sliders, then you could construct them like this.

- Layer 1: a grey filled rounded rectangle shape
- Layer 2: a duplicate of layer one, filled with a colour

Clip layer 2 to layer 1 by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+clicking on the line between both layers in the layers panel. The cursor changes to an icon like this shown circled in red

[image]

- Layer 3: a filled ellipse shape, i.e. the control

Then you can use the Move Tool to select both the circular control and colour filled rectangle. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click to make a multiple selection.

Now, as you click and drag the slider fill and the control, you can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to constrain the movement to a straight line.

Example:

[image]